# I block-padded and still get "data not block size aligned"

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

I have a problem when encrypting that causes the error:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: data not block size aligned
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2086)
    at com.lcp.sso.logic.SsoCipher.encode(SsoCipher.java:89)
```

The constructor for the object:

```
public MyCipher() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede", "BC");
    keyGen.init(new SecureRandom());
    SecretKey keySpec = keyGen.generateKey();

    this.sharedKey = keySpec.getEncoded().toString();
    this.encrypter = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/Nopadding", "BC");
    this.encrypter.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
    this.decrypter = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/Nopadding", "BC");
    this.decrypter.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
}
```

The method in which the error occurs:

```
public String encode(String arg_text) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    byte[] encrypt = arg_text.getBytes();

    if(encrypt.length % 8 != 0){ //not a multiple of 8
        //create a new array with a size which is a multiple of 8
        byte[] padded = new byte[encrypt.length + 8 - (encrypt.length % 8)];

        //copy the old array into it
        System.arraycopy(encrypt, 0, padded, 0, encrypt.length);
        encrypt = padded;
    }

    byte[] b = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafe(encrypt);
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypter.doFinal(b));
}
```

The error happens when calling that last method there.  I'd swear that I'm making it the right block size, there, by null-padding the byte array to make sure it's a multiple of 8.  I just don't know what went wrong!

I'm using:
Eclipse Version:  Juno Service Release 1
Server:  Tomcat v7.0 Server at Localhost ( specifically 7.0.32 )

--- **EDIT** ---

Program isn't working yet, (EDIT:  YES IT IS!  Muahahahaha!) but this problem is solved.

The constructor for the object:

```
public MyCipher() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidParameterSpecException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES", "BC");
    keyGen.init(new SecureRandom());
    SecretKey keySpec = keyGen.generateKey();

    this.sharedKey = new String( Base64.encodeBase64URLSafe( keySpec.getEncoded() ) );
    this.encrypter = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
    this.encrypter.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);

    AlgorithmParameters params = this.encrypter.getParameters();
    byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    this.sharedIV = new String( Base64.encodeBase64URLSafe( iv ) );
    this.decrypter = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
    this.decrypter.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
}
```

And the encrypting method is:

```
public String encode(String arg_text) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] encrypt = arg_text.getBytes();
    return new String( Base64.encodeBase64URLSafe(encrypter.doFinal(encrypt)), "US-ASCII");
}
```

It's now working to encrypt and decrypt just fine.  Thank you VERY much.

Comment: `N + 8 - (N%8)` - yes, this is always a multiple of 8.  1:  1 + 8 - 1 = 8, 2:  2 + 8 - 2 = 8, 17:  17 + 8 - 1 = 24, a multiple of 8.  Etc.  Alternatively, 3/8 + 8 is 8.375, which is not a multiple of 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strange code in some aspects. Begining by why your code doesn't work, you are making sure that the size of `encrypt` is a multiple of 8, but you are trying to cipher `byte[] b = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafe(encrypt);` which may not be a multiple of 8. The following code should work:

```
public String encode(String arg_text) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    byte[] encrypt = arg_text.getBytes();

    if(encrypt.length % 8 != 0){ //not a multiple of 8
        //create a new array with a size which is a multiple of 8
        byte[] padded = new byte[encrypt.length + 8 - (encrypt.length % 8)];

        //copy the old array into it
        System.arraycopy(encrypt, 0, padded, 0, encrypt.length);
        encrypt = padded;
    }

    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64URLSafe(encrypter.doFinal(b)), "US-ASCII");
}
```

Now, where there is `this.encrypter = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/Nopadding", "BC");` do you notice the "Nopadding" part of the string? Well, the code does what you ask it to do... but the library can do the padding work for you, you just have to tell it. Try `this.encrypter = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "BC");` instead and see if it works.

But really, why would you want to use 3DES in ECB mode? Unless the reason is legacy (which is unlikely from what I see here), it makes no sense. I believe you need to read a bit more about cryptography.

Comment: "I believe you need to read a bit more about cryptography."  Oh, that's entirely too true.  I've been trying for days to research modern cryptography, but I haven't found a reference that makes the assumption that you don't know what all these cryptography terms and methods and modes and whatnot mean.  A lot of them start off describing *what* cryptography is ... and then go into a riff on an alphabet jumble that makes me go, "Uhwuh?"  If you have a good reference suggestion, I'm eager for it.  "But really, why would you want to use 3DES in ECB mode?" - alphabet jumble.  "Uhwuh?"

Comment: I'm trying to expand on some legacy code to create a random key instead of accepting an already validated key from elsewhere - I was originally trying to use `DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`, and was getting a 'invalid key size' error.  Someone else told me to use the `DESede/ECB/Nopadding` you see there to fix the problem - and it did!  It just gave me a new problem.  I am fully willing to try out new settings and ideas, and learn better ways to do things, cause I'm positive I'm not doing this the best way I could.

Speaking of which, hold on a sec.  (noises of tinkering)

Comment: OK.  Commenting out the manual padding and making the change you suggested... still gets me the 'Illegal Key Size'.  Putting the manual padding back in and making the changes except for the PKCS5Padding change ... still gives me the "Illegal Key Size' error.  And it happens at the `this.encrypter.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);` line in the constructor.  Which makes no sense, because that means it should be before any changes.

Comment: You helped point me in the right direction, and I was able to find my way from there.  Thank you very much!

Comment: First of all, I'm happy my answer was helpful. I'll be editing it so that I explain you what 3DES in ECB mode is and why you should avoid it at all cost. Regarding good sources on "applied cryptography", I honestly can't suggest one book (which thinking of it, is indeed strange). I'm also definitely not an expert but I took a few graduate courses on the topic, I was always fond of it. Search Amazon for applied cryptography and buy some well rated book on it. It is really on of those topics where theory has to come BEFORE practice.

Comment: Fortunately, I got ahold of a friend of mine (sometime in the last four hours) who has theory AND practice, and he explained concepts to me as I went, "OH!  That concept from my cryptography courses back in college was ECB?" and "Ahhhh, yes, DES, Now I remember that."  So the theory was in there SOMEWHERE, My vocab database just dropped all its references.